# The implication of $H(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n) = nH(X_1)$

Tags: stochastic-processes, information-theory, entropy

Let $X_1,X_2,\dots ,X_n$ be a discrete random process and $$a_n=\frac{1}{n}H(X_1,X_2,\dots ,X_n)$$Suppose further that we have for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ $$a_n = a_{n+1}$$ I think this implies that $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n$ is an IID random process but I don't know how to prove it. Obviously, the equality condition implies for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ $$H(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n) = nH(X_1)$$ Does this last equality imply that entropies are equal? I.e. $$H(X_1) = H(X_2)=\dots=H(X_n)$$ For example for $n=2$ we have $$H(X_1,X_2)\le H(X_1)+H(X_2) \implies 2H(X_1)\le H(X_1)+H(X_2) \implies H(X_1)\le H(X_2)$$ The pattern doesn't seem to continue for $n=3$: $$H(X_1,X_2,X_3)\le H(X_1)+H(X_2)+H(X_3) \implies 3H(X_1)\le H(X_1)+H(X_2)+H(X_3) \implies 2H(X_1)\le H(X_2)+H(X_3)$$
**Edit:** The answer by Misha Lavrov shows that in general the random process isn't IID. If we add the assumption that $X_1,X_2,\dots ,X_n$ is a stationary process, can we reach the conclusion that RVs are independent and hence IID? By stationary I mean $$\text{Pr}\{X_1 = x_1, X_2 = x_2,...,X_n = x_n\} = \text{Pr}\{X_{1+l} = x_1, X_{2+l} = x_2,...,X_{n+l} = x_n\}$$ for all integer $l$ and $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, $X_1, \dots, X_n$ don't have to be either independent or identically distributed.

First of all, even if we did have $H(X_1) = H(X_2) = \dots = H(X_n)$, that doesn't tell us anything definite about the distributions of $X_1, \dots, X_n$. We can find lots of examples of different distributions with the same entropy.

Second, we do not know that the entropies of $X_1, \dots, X_n$ are equal; we only know that $H(X_1)$ is equal to $H(X_2 \mid X_1)$ which is equal to $H(X_3 \mid X_1,X_2)$ and so on; in general, $$H(X_1) = H(X_n \mid X_1, \dots, X_{n-1}).$$ But the unconditional entropy of $X_n$ can be very different. For example, suppose that $Y_1, Y_2, \dots$ is a sequence of independent uniform samples from $\{0,1\}$, and for all $n$, $X_n = Y_1 + Y_2 + \dots + Y_n$. Then $$H(X_1, \dots, X_n) = H(Y_1, \dots, Y_n) = n$$ (in bits) because either of the $n$-tuples $(X_1, \dots, X_n)$ and $(Y_1, \dots, Y_n)$ determines the other. However, the unconditional $H(X_n)$ keeps growing: the distribution of $X_n$ is $\text{Binomial}(n,\frac12)$ and so $H(X_n)$ grows roughly as $\frac12 \log_2 n$.

(The entropy $H(X_n)$ also does not have to keep increasing with $n$. For example, we could follow the pattern above for $X_1, \dots, X_{99}$ but then decide that $X_{100} = Y_{100}$, for a sudden drop in entropy.)

Intuitively, the condition in the question only says that the total entropy in the system increases linearly: nothing more and nothing less. The random variable $X_n$ only uses the same *new* amount of randomness, but can also depend on $X_1, \dots, X_{n-1}$ to increase its entropy.

---

One thing we can say is that **if** $X_1, \dots, X_n$ are identically distributed, **then** the entropy condition tells us that they are independent.

In this case, we know $H(X_1) = H(X_n)$ for all $n$, so an earlier equation becomes $$H(X_n) = H(X_n \mid X_1, \dots, X_{n-1}).$$ In general, $H(X) = H(X \mid Y)$ only if $X$ and $Y$ are independent; this can be proven by looking carefully at the definitions, but intuitively it holds because $H(X) = H(X \mid Y)$ tells us: "nothing about $X$ is learned by knowing $Y$". So in our case, $X_n$ is independent from $(X_1, \dots, X_{n-1})$ for each $n$, which means that all the random variables in our process are independent.

(In particular, for a stationary process, we know in particular that $X_1, X_2, \dots$ are identically distributed, and therefore they are IID.)

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. If we know that $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n$ is a stationary random process, can we prove that the process is IID?

Comment: Stationary as in $X_n$ has the same distribution for all $n$? This tells us $H(X_n) = H(X_1)$, but we already knew that $H(X_n \mid X_1, \dots, X_{n-1}) = H(X_1)$, which does tell us that $X_n$ is independent from $(X_1, \dots, X_{n-1})$: in general, $H(X\mid Y) = H(X)$ only if $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: Thanks. I think $H(X_n \mid X_1, \dots, X_{n-1}) = H(X_n)$ implies that $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n$ are independent and then using  $H(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n) = nH(X_1)$ we can conclude that $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n$ is an IID random process. Am I correct?

Comment: Uh, $H(X_n \mid X_1, \dots, X_{n-1}) = H(X_n)$ implies that they're independent, but to prove that we needed to make the assumption that they're identically distributed. We cannot prove that they're identically distributed if we do not already know it.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? By the stationary and $a_n = a_{n+1}$ assumptions we have proved that $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n$ are independent (without restoring to the distribution of RVs). Now by independence $H(X_1 , X_2) = H(X_1) + H(X_2) = 2H(X_1)$ which shows that $H(X_1) = H(X_2)$ and similarly $H(X_1) = \dots = H(X_n)$. I think this shows that they are identically distributed.

Comment: What do you mean by "stationary" if not "identically distributed"?

Comment: You are absolutely right :). The definition of stationary implies that RVs are identically distributed. By stationary I meant $$\text{Pr}\{X_1 = x_1, X_2 = x_2,...,X_n = x_n\}
= \text{Pr}\{X_{1+l} = x_1, X_{2+l} = x_2,...,X_{n+l} = x_n\}$$ for every $n$ and $l$. If we let $n=1$ then in fact we have assumed that RVs are identically distributed.

Comment: I've edited the question. I think it would be nice if you add your comments for the stationary case to the answer, if you like.